# MySQL Sales Report

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot, report

I have the following tables:

```
users
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| id    | source    | age_group |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 1     | google    | 18 - 22   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 2     | facebook  | 22 - 25   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 3     | site      | 25 - 35   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 4     | google    | 25 - 35   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 5     | google    | 18 - 22   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+

orders
+-------+-----------+
| id    | userId    |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | 3         |
+-------+-----------+
| 2     | 1         |
+-------+-----------+
| 3     | 3         |
+-------+-----------+
| 4     | 2         |
+-------+-----------+
| 5     | 4         |
+-------+-----------+
| 6     | 5         |
+-------+-----------+

orders_payments:
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| id    | orderId   | amount    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 1     | 1         | 10        |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 2     | 2         | 0         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 3     | 3         | 40        |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 4     | 5         | 0         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 5     | 6         | 0         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

And 3 possibilities:

1. User placed order and paid (orders_payments amount > 0)
2. User tried a service for free (orders_payments amount = 0)
3. User placed order but didn't show up (no record in orders_payments)

I need a sales report that looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| source    | age_group | paid      | tried     | no_show   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| google    | 18 - 22   | 0         | 2         | 0         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| google    | 25 - 35   | 0         | 1         | 0         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| facebook  | 22 - 25   | 0         | 0         | 1         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| site      | 25 - 35   | 1         | 0         | 0         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The last 3 columns represent the number of users that paid at least once, tried the services for free or didn't show up for the appointment.

The report is grouped by source and then by age_group. So something like this

```
SELECT source, age_group, ... FROM users GROUP BY source, age_group
```

I can't, for the life of me, figure it out.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

L.E.: I only want to count the users once. So if they have two paid orders I count them once as paid, if the tried but then paid I also want to count them once as paid and so on.

L.E.2: I think this is a possible solution:

```
select
    u.source,
    u.age_group,
    sum(op.amount > 0) paid,
    sum(op.amount = 0) tried,
    sum(op.orderId is null) no_show
from users u
inner join orders o on o.userId = u.id
left join (
    select max(amount) as amount, orderId
    from orders_payments
    left join orders on orders_payments.orderId = orders.id
    group by orders.userId
) op on op.orderId = o.id
group by u.source, u.age_group
order by u.source, u.age_group
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a `left join` on the payments table, and then conditional aggregation.

```
select
    u.source,
    u.age_group,
    sum(op.amount > 0) paid,
    sum(op.amount = 0) tried,
    sum(op.orderId is null) no_show
from users u
inner join orders o on o.userId = u.id
left join orders_payments op on op.orderId = o.id
group by u.source, u.age_group
order by u.source, u.age_group
```

Comment: Thanks, @GMB! The only problem is that it's counting user #3 twice because he has 2 orders. I only want to count him once.
Also, if he tried but then also paid, I only want to count him as paid.

Comment: I think I found a solution (updated the answer). Not sure how clean it is.